# array_intersect_key with three array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have three array from dynamic data in php for example :

```
array1 = array('10-11-2015'=>23.6,
               '25-11-2015'=>48.6,
               '12-11-2015'=>14.52);

array2 = array('10-11-2015'=>8.7,
               '22-10-2015'=>86.6,
               '12-11-2015'=>78.5);

array3 = array('10-11-2015'=>5.8,
               '19-09-2015'=>3.6,
               '12-11-2015'=>96.4);
```

I just need common keys from this three array

```
newarray = array('10-11-2015','12-11-2015');
```

I use `array_intersect_key` but it is for only two array.

How I can get it form three or more array ?

Comment: "but it is for only two array" the [function definition](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) is `array array_intersect_key ( array $array1 , array $array2 [, array $... ] )`. So, no, it is not for "only two arrays".

Comment: @Pete sorry but I don't know how to use for more then two array in `array array_intersect_key`

Comment: @Pete, you are right, I can use three array. thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
array_keys(array_intersect_key($array1, $array2, $array3));
```